# How to solve Doctrine DBAL Exception when moving a Zend project to a new server

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am moving a Zend framework project to a new server. The project was built by another developer and uses Doctrine, which I have not used myself so I am a bit lost as to fix the error.

I have run some other zend projects on the target server (running ubuntu 14.04) without issue but with this project I get a Doctrine DBAL exception.

The error I am getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException' with
>   message 'The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if no PDO
>   instance is given to DriverManager::getConnection().' in
>   /**projectpath**/library/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:60 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /**projectpath**/library/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php(173):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverRequired() #1
>   /**projectpath**/library/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php(136):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::_checkParams(Array) #2
>   /**projectpath**/www/toolbox/library/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(938):
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(Array,
>   Object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration),
>   Object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)) #3
>   /**projectpath**/www/toolbox/application/Bootstrap.php(151):
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(Array,
>   Object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)) #4
>   /**projectpath**/www/toolbox/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669):
>   Bootstrap->_initDoctrine() #5
>   /**projectpath**/www/toolbox/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Boo in
>   /**projectpath**/www/toolbox/library/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php on line 60

Answer (score 1):

### This answer relates to Zend Framework 2 config:

In your **Zend Framework 2** project there is an `autoload` folder.

```
\config\autoload
```

In this folder you should make all the appropriate `*.local.php` files with the configuration options for your new server (where you migrate the project to).

One of them is for doctrine and should contain something like this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'dbname' => 'database',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Read more on configuration of your application **[in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html)**

Comment: @Finglish Did it solve your problem? Or still not up and running?

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced I replied to this already.  Your solution wasn't the complete answer for me, but it lead me to the solution which was that despite what I had been told the app was actually ZF1 not 2 and so the doctrine settings were defined in the application.ini file.  I marked your answer up as its accurate for ZF2 and describing the structure made me realise I was looking at the wrong ZF documentation :).  Thanks!

Comment: @Finglish I removed the zend-framework2 tag from your question. It is obviously important that you add the correct tags to get the correct help. Good that you solved it...

Comment: Noted, but at the time of asking I had been told the project ZF2, hence the tag. Thanks for updating.